# Linq to SQL .Any() with multiple conditions?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'm trying to use .Any() in an if statement like so:

```
if(this.db.Users.Any(x => x.UserID == UserID)){
    // do stuff
}
```

Is there a way I can put multiple conditions inside of the .Any()?  For example something like:

```
if(this.db.Users.Any(x => x.UserID == UserID AND x.UserName == UserName)){
    // do stuff
}
```

Or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Sure, use the `&&` operator.

```
if(this.db.Users.Any(x => x.UserID == UserID && x.UserName == UserName)){
    // do stuff
}
```

If you can use it in an `if` statement, you can use it here.  The lambda needs to evaluate to a bool.

Comment: Doh! I tried that earlier but I was getting an error, apparently something else was incorrect at the time.  Thanks!

Comment: How can we specify blocks of conditions. e.g. .Any((x => x.UserID == UserID && x.UserName == UserName) || <<Some condition>> && <<Some condition>>)

Comment: @VijayBalkawade just like that.  if you can  use it in an `if` statement, then you can use it here.

Comment: Will this translate to an `Exists`? Or a `Count > 0`?

Answer (score 7):

```
if(this.db.Users.Any(x => x.UserID == UserID && x.UserName == UserName)){
    // do stuff
}
```